# React Native : Why is my FlatList overlapping The View above it

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList component imported from another file and displayed below a View that has two TouchableOpacity components. I intent to use touchableOpacity Components as tabs for generating FlatList with different data. But when the list is rendered, the top most item is overlapping with the View that has got touchableOpacity Tabs and I just cant seem to figure out what the problem is.
[image]

The View in question is as follows which itself is in a main container view

```
<View style = {styles.jobsWorkContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.handleJobsChange}>
              <Text style = {this.state.postedJobsActivated ? (styles.jobsHeadingActive) : (styles.jobsHeadings)}>Posted Jobs</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.handleJobsChange}>
              <Text style = {this.state.postedJobsActivated ? (styles.jobsHeadings) : (styles.jobsHeadingActive)}>Completed Jobs</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          {
            (this.state.postedJobsActivated) ? (
              <JobsList jobsData = {this.state.testData}/>
            ) : (
            <View style = {{top : 50}}>
              <Text>Here a similar list would appear for the jobs the user has completed</Text>
            </View>
          )
          }
```

The style for the View above is

```
jobsWorkContainer : {
//backgroundColor : "yellow",
flexDirection : "row",
top: "5%",
width : "100%",
justifyContent : "space-evenly",
borderBottomColor : "antiquewhite",
borderBottomWidth : 2,
```

},

The `<Joblist/>` is the FlatList I am importing from another file
as follows

```
    const renderJobList = (obj) =>{
  let source
  let navigation = obj.item.navigation
  /*than delete navigation object so that obj.item can be passed without any
  warning to the jobdetail page */
  delete obj.item.navigation
  //to solve the bug of sending dynamic require links for image tag in react native
  switch(obj.item.job)
  {
    case "carpenter":
      source= require(`./assets/carpenter.png`)
      break;
    case "painter":
      source = require(`./assets/painter.png`)
      break;
    case "electrician":
      source = require(`./assets/electrician.png`)
      break;
    case "plumber":
      source = require(`./assets/plumber.png`)
      break;
    default :
      source = require(`./assets/briefcase2.png`)
  }
  return (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style = {{top : 24}}
    onPress = {()=> navigation.navigate("jobDetail", obj.item)}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Image
          style = {{height : 50, width : 50}}
          source = {source}/>
      </View>
      <View style = {{left : 20}}>
        <Text style = {styles.jobHeading}>{obj.item.title}</Text>
      </View>


    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>

)
}


const JobsList = (props) => {
  //to have navigation object available to this component that is not a navigation screen
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  /*adding the navigation object to every object of the data so that it
  is availabel to every rendered item in renderItem of flatlist*/
  let data = props.jobsData.map((ob)=> {
    return {
      ...ob, navigation
    }
  })
  return (
  <FlatList
    renderItem = {renderJobList}
    data = {data}
    keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index.toString()}
    contentContainerStyle = {{bottom : "5%",}}/>
)
}




JobsList.propTypes = {
  jobsData : PropTypes.array
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    padding : 20,
    borderColor: "grey",
    borderBottomWidth : 3,
    alignItems : "center",
    width : Math.round(Dimensions.get("window").width),
    flexDirection : "row",

  },
  jobHeading : {
    textDecorationLine : "underline",
    padding: 10,
    fontSize : 20,
  }
})



export default JobsList
```

Comment: add <View> in your jobs container around JobList, and add appropriate style e.g. top: 100. Currently it's not in the styles.jobsWorkContainer view container.

Comment: adding a <View> around <JobList/> stops the scroll able feature of the FlatList

Comment: You need to set the height. View does not affect flatlets scroll.

Comment: ok setting the height is solving it but how do I set the height so that it fills the rest of the screen and also the last item doesnot get cut off by the bottomtabnavigator, cuz giving the height in % is stopping the scroll feature